# Forward C++ Exceptions from CLI to C#

Tags: c#, c++, exception, c++-cli, dotnet-cli

I am wrapping a C++ library via CLI into C#.

File from **C++ Library**:

```cpp
/* cpp_lib/Date.hpp */

namespace cpp_lib
{
    struct Date
    {
        Date(int year, int month, int day)
        {
            if (1 > month || month > 12)
                throw std::out_of_range("Month is out of range");
            ...
        }
    };
}
```

File from **CLI Wrapper**:

```cpp
/* cli_lib/Date.hpp */

#include <cpp_lib/Date.hpp>
#include "ManagedObject.hpp"

namespace CLI_Lib
{
    public ref class Date : public ManagedObject<cpp_lib::Date>
    {
    public:
        Date(int year, int month, int day);
            : ManagedObject(new cpp_lib::Date(year, month, day)) { }
    };
}
```

where `ManagedObject.hpp` comes from [Creating a C++/CLI Wrapper](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/development/dotnet-development/creating-ccli-wrapper/).

**Sample C# Script**:

```cs
/* Program.cs */

using CLI_Lib;

namespace My_Script
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Date d1 = new Date(2025, 12, 25);
                Date d2 = new Date(2026, 13, 25);  // Will throw because 13 is not a month
                Console.WriteLine("Dates are OK");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {e.ToString()}");
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

The C# Script produces this output:

```
ERROR: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: External component has thrown an exception.
   at cpp_lib.Date.{ctor}(Date* , Int32 , Int32 , Int32 )
   at CLI_Lib.Date..ctor(Int32 year, Int32 month, Int32 day) in ...\Date.cpp:line 12
   at My_Script.Program.Main(String[] args) in ...\Program.cs:line 25
```

The problem is, there is no mention of `"Month is out of range"`. **Is there a way to simply forward the original C++ error message to C#?**

I kind of found a way to do this by tweaking `cli_lib/Date.hpp` like so:

```cpp
namespace CLI_Lib
{
    public ref class Date : public ManagedObject<cpp_lib::Date>
    {
    public:
        Date::Date(int year, int month, int day)
            : ManagedObject()
        {
            try
            {
                m_Instance = new cpp_lib::Date(year, month, day);
            }
            catch (const std::exception& e)
            {
                throw gcnew Exception(char_arr_to_csharp_string(e.what()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this feels very clunky, and requires me to add these `try-catch` constructs all over the place. **Is there a better way?**

Comment: No there is no simple way, you're crossing a technology boundary (C++ -> C#) and this means you have to translate all exceptions from C++ to C# exceptions manually. (Or come up with some clever exception translation mechanism where you can plugin translations from C++ to C# exceptions (but that's probably overkill for you)

Comment: If you are aware of a way to create a "clever exception translation mechanism", even if it means a lot of work on my side, I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: However clever the translation mechanism is you still need something like catch(...) { translate_exceptions(); } all over the place.

Comment: Yes it means trying/rethrowing etc.

Answer (score 0):

No, this cannot be handled automatically.

The usual approach, is to write some macro code, and wrap all your native calls. E.g., like so

```
#define BEGIN_EH try {
#define END_EH } catch (std::exception& e) { /* ... */ }

void ManagedFoo()
{
  BEGIN_EH;

  nativeFoo();

  END_EH;
}
```

Note, that the semicolons after the macros are superfluous, but can help the IDE when formatting the code.